# Laravel Left Join with a tricky filter

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, join, left-join

I am assigning unique users to vouchers on my website.1 user may have more than one voucher assigned to them but cannot be assigned the same voucher twice.
I have 2 mysql tables that I am fetching data from. 
**tbl_users**
[image]

**tbl_voucher_users**
[image]

When a user click on a button on my website, they pass along a **voucher_id** with which I use to display eligible users that can be assigned this voucher ( I.e Users that have not been assigned to this voucher ).
Below is how I am getting the users where **voucher_id = 8**

```
$user_data = DB::table('users')
        ->leftJoin('voucher_users', 'users.id', '=', 'voucher_users.user_id')
        ->where('voucher_users.voucher_id','!=',8) //User not assigned this voucher
        ->select('users.*','users.id as userID','voucher_users.*')
        ->get();
```

**My problem**
I am able to left join **without the where clause** and get results from both Users table and Voucher_users table having **eliminated all users assigned voucher_id=8**.
However, the results also include **users who are assigned other vouchers but also the voucher I am assigning.**
i.e
Expected resulsts would be users: **8,11,12,13,14** having eliminated users: **1,4** 
But my current results are:**4,8,11,12,13,14**
How do I get rid of the user 4 to prevent double assignment?

Comment: I would suggest at `not exists` approach

Comment: That would be very welcome, I just want it to work. Kindly demo if you may

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion above by @Kevin Lynch to use NOT EXIST .. I simplified the code to:

```
SELECT users.*
FROM
users
WHERE
NOT EXISTS(SELECT user_id FROM voucher_users WHERE voucher_users.user_id = users.id AND voucher_id=9)
```

It works so far, I can then covert it to Laravel style

Answer (score 0):

`NOT EXISTS` would be a good solution if this were to remain a small project (or if you could put more constraints on the users to keep the dataset small perhaps by limiting based on user created date or similar).

However if you can't do such a thing, this query will eventually give you problems because under the hood, mysql will be running that sub-query for each record returned in the main query.  You can check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-materialization.html for more information.

A different solution which would handle the scaling quite a bit better would be to generate a temporary table of users that have the voucher you are looking to remove...

```
create temporary table tmp_voucher_user (user_id int not null, primary key (user_id)) as 
select distinct user_id from voucher_users where voucher_id = 8;
```

Now that we have a table of users we which to remove, all we need to do is worry about a simple left join...

```
select users.*, user_voucher.*
from users
inner join user_voucher on users.id = user_voucher.user_id
left join tmp_voucher_user on users.id = tmp_voucher_user.user_id
where tmp_voucher_user.user_id is null -- this part is important, it's only going to grab users where there isn't a match on tmp_user_voucher
```

Unfortunately this isn't as clean as just doing a `NOT EXISTS` and I don't believe Laravel supports a way to build temporary tables outside of just writing a raw query but it should scale quite a bit better.